# Statically compiling with SWI Prolog

Tags: compilation, swi-prolog

I have been using SWI Prolog for a while and I am a little unhappy about the interpreted nature of it. When I found the `qsave_program/2` I though I was in for a treat. I wasn't. Apparently SWIPL doesn't actually statically compile, even with `qsave_program('foo.exe', [stand_alone(true), goal(foo(X))])`.

This is what I have done:
 From the GUI console, I have loaded the source file *.pl with `consult/1`,

I do a test and query `foo(X)` and get the expected result,

I submit the command `qsave_program/2` as above (with real input of course),

I attempt to run the program foo.exe,

I receive a system error, outlining the execution error which states that 'libswpl.dll does not 
exist' (I am running windows of course),

I rage at SWIPL.

I have noticed that libswipl.dll does exist - in the SWI Prolog program file that is! I can successfully run the program in this location, which is in the same directory as SWIPL-win.exe

I ask you: what am I missing? Do I need to do any other precompiling for SWI Prolog?

Comment: Is the SWIPL program folder (that has the DLL in question) in your PATH environment variable? It's not unusual for application distribution to require also the distribution of DLLs. This is true with most tools from Microsoft, etc. Sometimes there is an option to build it all into a monolithic EXE file, but not as the typical case.

Comment: I have not set an environment variable for Prolog manually. Why would the compiler require it's own directory path? I thought it would be smart enough to package everything together where I am saving the .EXE. I could manually copy .dll's but that seems a little bit awkward: which do I copy?

Comment: I'm suggesting that, in order to run the EXE, it would need to find the DLL that it depends on. So the DLL would need to be in the same directory as the EXE, or in your executable PATH. That is the case with any executable program.

Comment: Of course the program needs to find the .dll's. My question is why doesn't the SWIPL compiler copy the required .dll's into the compilation directory? The SWIPL manual promises that the compiled program is completely standalone. In my experience, it isn't: SWIPL doesn't include the .dll's upon compilation.

Comment: The word "standalone" here means that you don't need the swipl enviroment executable. I don't see anything in the documentation that promises anything quite as specific as you are suggesting. They use the word "standalone" without much further explanation. I do think that the documentation is lacking in explaining the feature in adequate detail. I do find it a little "disingenuous".

Comment: Does this mean that I don't need swipl.exe but I do need everything else in the program file? Hardly a standalone compilation if you ask me. I want to be able to distribute the program without having the end user to install Prolog. IS THAT TOO MUCH TO ASK, SWIPL!!!